# Duplicate task copies when exporting project data to excel

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm trying to copy over my  project data into  excel. The code copies into excel, but some of the tasks are duplicated and copied over twice. The dates for the duplicated tasks are also not copied over correctly. Any idea why some tasks duplicate/have inaccurate dates?

I only want to copy over task level summaries, that are either outline level 3 or 4. And I want to copy over 3 sets of dates forecasted, baseline and actual.

```
Sub StartExcel()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim proj As Project
Dim t As Task
Dim pj As Project

Dim TskID() As Integer
Dim TskNam() As String
Dim WBS() As String
Dim UID() As Integer
Dim FStart() As String
Dim FFinish() As String
Dim BStart() As String
Dim BFinish() As String
Dim AStart() As String
Dim AFinish() As String
Dim Entity() As String

Dim NumTsk As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, RowIndex As Integer
Dim BookNam As String
Dim c As Range


'Open Excel workbook called "Test"

Set pj = ActiveProject
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Test.xlsm")
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(3)

'Organize project data into an array
SelectTaskColumn
NumTsk = ActiveSelection.tasks.Count
ReDim TskID(NumTsk), UID(NumTsk), TskNam(NumTsk), WBS(NumTsk), Duration(NumTsk)
ReDim FStart(NumTsk), FFinish(NumTsk), BStart(NumTsk), BFinish(NumTsk), 
AStart(NumTsk), AFinish(NumTsk)

    Application.Caption = "Progress"
    ActiveWindow.Caption = "Gathering Project data into arrays"

    'select array data
    i = 1
    For Each t In ActiveSelection.tasks
     If t.Text2 = "task" And Not t Is Nothing Then
            UID(i) = t.UniqueID
            TskNam(i) = t.Name
            WBS(i) = t.WBS
            FStart(i) = t.ScheduledStart
            FStart(i) = t.ScheduledFinish
            BFinish(i) = t.BaselineStart
            BFinish(i) = t.BaselineFinish
            AStart(i) = t.ActualStart
            AFinish(i) = t.ActualFinish
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next t

    'Copy array data into excel worksheet

    ActiveWindow.Caption = "Writing data to worksheet"
    Set c = xlSheet.Range("A1")
    RowIndex = 0
    For j = 1 To i - 1
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 0).value = UID(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 1).value = TskNam(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 2).value = WBS(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 3).value = FStart(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 4).value = FFinish(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 5).value = BStart(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 6).value = BFinish(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 7).value = AStart(j)
        c.Offset(RowIndex, 8).value = AFinish(j)
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    Next j

    For Each t In pj.tasks
     If t.Text2 = "task" And Not t Is Nothing Then
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 1).value = t.UniqueID
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 2).value = t.Name
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 3).value = t.WBS
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 4).value = t.ScheduledStart
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 5).value = t.ScheduledFinish
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 6).value = t.BaselineStart
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 7).value = t.BaselineFinish
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 8).value = t.ActualStart
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 9).value = t.ActualFinish

    End If
    Next t

    'Format excel sheet
    xlSheet.Columns("A").AutoFit
    xlSheet.Columns("C:J").ColumnWidth = 13
    xlSheet.Columns("D:J").NumberFormat = "m/d/yy"
    xlSheet.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 30
    xlSheet.Columns("A:F").VerticalAlignment = xlTop 'reference
    xlSheet.Range("C:D").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft 'reference


    xlApp.Visible = True

    'Tidy up
        xlApp.UserControl = True
        Set xlApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Retagged [tag:ms-project] as I think that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a problem due to loading different arrays for all your variables. If any one of them doesn't load a value for whatever reason, then the indexes could get thrown off. Have you tried making a single multi-dimensional array to store each tasks values, then pasting the entire array into Excel all at once?